# How To pass the variable name in mysql query using python

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql

Myquery is inserted if i give the static value in fields.but throws exception if i give the variable name.
My Working code

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pass","selvapractice" )

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO selva(name) \
       VALUES ('Selva') " 
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
except: 
   print "dffds"
   db.rollback()

db.close()
```

My Exception Code

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pass","selvapractice" )

cursor = db.cursor()
a="surya"
sql = "INSERT INTO selva(name) \
       VALUES (%s) " %(a)
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
except: 
   print "dffds"
   db.rollback()

db.close()
```

It prints dfffds

How to give the variable name in query?Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nothing at all like that.

Comment: i checked it prints dfffds in except block

Comment: http://halfcooked.com/presentations/osdc2006/python_databases.html

Comment: @Ignacio,I found out the mistake,the issus is i put (%s) instead of ('%s').now i added the single quotes in my query it works fine.Thanks for your help to identify the problem.

Comment: **That's not how to fix it. That's how you create an insecure system.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Note how I am passing the variable as a param to the execute function, this is better to prevent sql injection attacks.

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pass","selvapractice" )

cursor = db.cursor()
a="surya"
b="male"
sql = "INSERT INTO selva(name, gender) VALUES (%s, %s)"
try:
   cursor.execute(sql, [a, b])
   db.commit()
except: 
   print "dffds"
   db.rollback()

db.close()
```

Comment: Thanks,It's works.can you give any example for giving one or more variables in query?

Comment: Just updatd my example with two variables, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES ('selva')
```

Comment: you gave the static values for name.This query works for me.My question is how to give variable name instead of static value (selva)

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES ('$name')